# Is there a technique to have a VBA statement update whenever a template is copied and pasted to a new location, on the SAME worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I've set up an Excel spreadsheet to follow my stock option trades.
I have templates for the various option trades (e.g., iron condor, Bull debit spread).
I calculate, at one minute intervals, profit / loss (P/L) and compare to my
target profit. Recently, I added an alert which requires VBA coding.

I would like to copy my options template and paste it on the ***same***
worksheet and have the pasted function work without having to write a
new VBA statement for every new options position (i.e., every time that I copy and paste my options trade template).

I have tried both absolute and relative naming of the Range values,
neither of which worked after pasting the options template (which contains the VBA alert code) in a new position.

I have resorted to multiple If statements which work but the coding
is messy and I have to write a new VBA "If statement" for every new
options position.

Is there a technique to have the VBA statement update whenever a  template is copied and pasted to a new location, on the SAME worksheet?

---

Sample VBA "If statements": consider first two If statements as the templates
and the last as copied and pasted to a new location.

---

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("$K$10").Value >= Range("$L$9").Value Then
MsgBox Prompt:="Option has exceded target, CASH IN! ", Title:="OPTION ALERT"
End If

If Range("$K$20").Value >= Range("$L$19").Value Then
MsgBox Prompt:="Option has exceded target, CASH IN! ", Title:="OPTION ALERT"
End If

.
.
.


If Range("$K$249").Value >= Range("$L$248").Value Then
MsgBox Prompt:="Option has exceded target, CASH IN!", Title:="OPTION ALERT"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Would a for loop to the last row not work? eg. `For i = 10 To Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Sounds like a great solution if the cells were continuous. Unfortunately, there are several rows between Range cells , some with numbers which would compare to texts, giving false positive on every minute update. Nice suggestion, just won't work in my case.

Comment: And are your cells you want to check not continuously the same distance apart? If they are you can `Step` in the For loop to skip every x cells. Or use a helper column to determine the rows you do want to calculate then loop based off of those. Without seeing your actual sheet though, it's hard to know what could work for your case as it's not completely clear to me your arrangement.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, not a fixed number of rows. The templates for specific options strategies vary in the number of rows. When I add a template for the option trade, I position on the spreadsheet by expiration date, rather than trade strategy (which vary between 7 and 10 rows). The spreadsheet can be up to 300 to 400 rows which is the reason for wanting an alert, in addition to conditional formatting to have the profit cell turn bright yellow to draw attention. An alert prevents having to continuously scroll to look for cells which have achieved the goal.

Comment: Well if you have conditional formatting which check the cells, then you can simply use VBA to find the cells that are highlighted and report their position or whatever you want to do. You find conditional formatted cell color by using: `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`.

Comment: I thought so, too. That was my first approach. I found the code (below) but no alerts were produced when I changed cell fill (tried both vbRed and vbYellow and confirmed RGB values) manually. Do you see a problem with this code?   =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=  Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Range("a" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
            MsgBox "See OPTION change"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Comment: I tested it and it works. Make sure you are using the right yellow for your conditional formatting. In the conditional formatting go Edit Rule > Format... > Fill > More Colors... > Custom and check the RGB. You can use RGB in your vba code too to make sure it's exact. Then I suggest just testing it in a normal sub. Now that I see it, it probably doesn't work because you're using it on `Workbook_open` and you don't specify the sheet for the range in your loop. do `Activesheet.Range("A" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbYellow` or instead of vbYellow do `RGB(255,255,0)`.

Comment: Nevermind I tested it as `Workbook_Open` and it still works with just Range rather than Activesheet.Range as long as your book opens on the right sheet (assuming you have more than one). It must be your colours so try with RGB so it's exact and see.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your input. I made changes suggested and changed to RGB values but still no joy - no alert on change of fill color. Perhaps it's something intrinsic to my computer or version of Excel. I don't know. Thanks.